# Android: Emulator can't pull from database / Extremely slow?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin, android-emulator

So I had my Android Emulator working perfectly fine yesterday and the day before, a Pixel 3a XL 28. Worked like a charm.

I restarted my computer and this morning, and now NONE of the emulators are working at all.

Early in the day, it was sort of working but it was extremely slow, and now it won't work at all.

I just get a blank white screen. My code is running, and I am just getting an error in my code that my database document doesn't exist, even though it does, and it takes a good minute or two to get to the database call in the first place. I am on a Mac OS.

I have an android phone that I just ran the code on, and it works like a charm.

```
 FirebaseFirestore.getInstance()
                .collection("Users")
                .document("hjkyilk")
                .get()
                .addOnSuccessListener { result ->
                    ...

                }
                .addOnFailureListener { exception ->
                    // Always hitting this, although this database DEFINITELY exists
                    println("User doesn't exist")
                }
```

with this error:

```
2020-02-05 14:58:47.751 5504-5504/com.example.casualdatingapp E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
2020-02-05 14:58:47.779 5504-5504/com.example.casualdatingapp E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
2020-02-05 14:58:47.814 5504-5504/com.example.casualdatingapp E/ResourcesCompat: Failed to find font-family tag
2020-02-05 14:58:48.069 5504-5575/com.example.casualdatingapp E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.
2020-02-05 14:58:48.124 5504-5605/com.example.casualdatingapp E/eglCodecCommon: GoldfishAddressSpaceHostMemoryAllocator: ioctl_ping failed for device_type=5, ret=-1
2020-02-05 14:58:49.803 5504-5504/com.example.casualdatingapp E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-02-05 14:58:49.842 5504-5575/com.example.casualdatingapp E/FirebaseInstanceId: Topic sync or token retrieval failed on hard failure exceptions: AUTHENTICATION_FAILED. Won't retry the operation.
```

What in the world is going on here? I have tried cold booting, installing new OS/Emulators, wiping the data on the emulators, nothing is working.

EDIT: It's worth noting when it worked this morning, it wasn't able to pull or write to my database at all, but the data it was trying to write was stored somewhere else. My database was never updated, but when I opened the emulator, the new content was still there. I don't even know how that's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I had a completely separate virtual UNIX server running on my computer and apparently it was constantly killing the processes of the emulator...

Don't run more than 1 virtual server at a time.